# Springboot Sessions unable to recognize my custom memory store for storing session data and uses default Session

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I have my own in-memory storage implementation. I want to use it with spring sessions to store the spring session data. I have looked at redis implementation and tried to follow that approach. I have created a CustomSessionRepository class that implements SessionRepository and have created annotation to use in the test application.

```
public class CustomSessionRepository implements SessionRepository<CustomSessionRepository.CustomSession> {
    public static final String DEFAULT_KEY_NAMESPACE = "spring:session";
    private Duration defaultMaxInactiveInterval = Duration.ofSeconds(MapSession.DEFAULT_MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL_SECONDS);
    private FlushMode flushMode = FlushMode.ON_SAVE;

    private SaveMode saveMode = SaveMode.ON_SET_ATTRIBUTE;

        //getter setters

        // the implementations
        @Override
    public CustomSession createSession() {
        MapSession cached = new MapSession();
        cached.setMaxInactiveInterval(this.defaultMaxInactiveInterval);
        CustomSessionsession = new CustomSession(cached, true);
        session.flushIfRequired();
        return session;
    }
        @Override
    public void save(CustomSessionsession) {
        if (!session.isNew) {
            String key = getSessionKey(session.hasChangedSessionId() ? session.originalSessionId : session.getId());
            Boolean sessionExists = this.sessionNCacheOperations.hasKey(key);
            if (sessionExists == null || !sessionExists) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Session was invalidated");
            }
        }
        session.save();
    }

        @Override
    public findById(String sessionId) {
        // ... code
        }

        @Override
    public deleteById(String sessionId) {
        // ... code
        }

        final class CustomSession implements Session {

        // getAttribute
        // getAttributeNames
        // setAttribute
        // removeAttribute
        // getCreationTime
        // setLastAccessedTime
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the config.annotations.web.http package i have the annotation and the annotation config:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@Import(CustomHttpSessionConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableCustomHttpSession {
    int maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds() default MapSession.DEFAULT_MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL_SECONDS;
    FlushMode flushMode() default FlushMode.ON_SAVE;
    SaveMode saveMode() default SaveMode.ON_SET_ATTRIBUTE;
}
```

```
public class NcacheHttpSessionConfiguration extends AbstractCustomHttpSessionConfiguration implements EmbeddedValueResolverAware, ImportAware {

    private StringValueResolver embeddedValueResolver;
    @Override
    public void setEmbeddedValueResolver(StringValueResolver resolver) {
        this.embeddedValueResolver = resolver;
    }
       
@Bean
    @Override
    public CustomSessionRepository sessionRepository() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start to connect");
        CustomSessionRepository  sessionRepository = new CustomSessionRepository (CacheManager.getCache(HelperStrings.CACHE_NAME));
        System.out.println("Found the cache store");
        sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(MapSession.DEFAULT_MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL);
        sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ON_SAVE);
        sessionRepository.setSaveMode(SaveMode.ON_SET_ATTRIBUTE);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(HelperStrings.DEFAULT_KEY_NAMESPACE)) {
            sessionRepository.setCustomNamespace(HelperStrings.DEFAULT_KEY_NAMESPACE);
        }
        return sessionRepository;
    }

public void setImportMetadata(AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata) {
        Map<String, Object> attributeMap = annotationMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(EnableCustomSession.class.getName());
        AnnotationAttributes attributes = AnnotationAttributes.fromMap(attributeMap);
        if (attributes == null) return;
        this.maxInactiveInterval = Duration.ofSeconds((long) (Integer)attributes.getNumber(HelperStrings.MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL));
        String customNamespaceValue = attributes.getString("namespace");
        if(StringUtils.hasText(redisNamespaceValue)) {
            customNamespace = this.embeddedValueResolver.resolveStringValue(customNamespaceValue );
        }
        flushMode = (FlushMode) attributes.getEnum("flushMode");
        saveMode = (SaveMode) attributes.getEnum("saveMode");
    }
}
```

Now I have installed this package as maven and then referenced this in my test spring session security project. When the app starts I can see the console logs from the sessionRepository() i.e. connecting to cache etc. But after that when I login with the spring security password in form, the JSESSIONID cookie is created and nothing is added to my custom store. I suppose it uses the default http Sesssions.

I have the test app like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableCustomSession
public class CustomSpringSessionApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomSpringSessionApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    String hello(  ) {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any more detail.

I tried logging in with spring security session app. I expected it to store that session in my custom store or at least reach that store functions but spring does not recognize it or fails to reach that.